# MYSQL - Grab value from different row and return them on the same row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4, pivot

I am working on an multi-language website with Laravel 4 and I am using a translation package called waavi translation, in short grabs the language text files of laravel and saves them to the db.

I am having an issue retrieving the data in a coherent manner to display them with datatables to create a language translation interface.

The table structures is as follow:

Languages Table:

```
id | locale | name
---------------------
1  | en     | english
2  | fr     | french
```

etc...

Language_entries Table:

```
id  | language_id | namespace | group       | item         | text
--------------------------------------------------------------------
.....
9   | 1           | *         | permissions | save.success | :name has successfully been saved.
....
102 | 2           | *         | permissions | save.success | :name a bien été sauvegardé.
.....
```

The query result I am looking for is:

```
group       | item         | en                                 | fr 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
permissions | save.success | :name has successfully been saved. | :name a bien été sauvegardé.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: why do you need results in this way? if you are translating, cant you just do select text from language_entries inner join languages on language.id = language_entries.language_id where locale = "something" and group = 'something' and item = 'something'? how will you know how much columns will you have in query when that depend on how much locales you have in db. that query will not be very flexible.

Comment: The generic name for this way of presenting result-sets is "pivoting."

Comment: @BojanKovacevic I will not be the only one translating the site, the interface will be used by the client and I think this way of displaying the data makes sense user-wise.  I'll definitely use a variante of your query to update the db though. Thanks.

Comment: @OllieJones That was exactly what I was looking for, I wasn't familiar with that term, a quick search gave me quite a few result to learn from.  Time to play with it, Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than 2 locale you can use a dynamic version,for your original question.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN locale= ''',
      locale,
      ''' THEN text END) AS ',
      locale
    )
   )INTO @sql
FROM language_entries t
JOIN languages l
ON t.language_id=l.id
GROUP BY `group`,item;



SET @sql=CONCAT('SELECT `group`,item,',@sql,' FROM
language_entries t
JOIN languages l
ON t.language_id=l.id
GROUP BY `group`,item');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Or just the non dynamic version

```
SELECT `group`,
item,
MAX(CASE WHEN locale= 'en' THEN text END) AS en
,MAX(CASE WHEN locale= 'et' THEN text END) AS et
FROM language_entries t 
JOIN languages l 
ON t.language_id=l.id 
GROUP BY `group`,item
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95c57/5)

Comment: Would it be possible to modify this SQL to take 2 or 3 variables of what locales to take? If so how could it be done?

Answer (score 2):

Taking user's @Notulysses answer. You can use the SQL query in Laravel (tested on 4.0) like so:

```
DB::table(DB::raw('language_entries t2'))
  ->select(
    't2.group',
    't2.item',
    DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(IF(t1.locale = "en", t2.`text`, NULL)) AS en'),
    DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(IF(t1.locale = "fr", t2.`text`, NULL)) AS fr')
  )
  ->leftJoin(DB::raw('languages t1'), function($join)
  {
    $join->on('t1.id', '=', 't2.language_id');
  })
  ->groupBy('t2.group', 't2.item')
  ->get();
```

The reason why I'm using `DB::raw('')` inside `DB::table()` is because Laravel would turn `language_entries t2` to `'language_entries t2'` which would break the query. Same reason in select and left join.

If you would want to use a variable instead of manually adding locales then make sure you use

```
DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote("Safe")
```

To keep the query safe.

Answer (score 1):

As it is said above this problem is called pivot and I can suggest you the following solution, using multiple `IF` conditions (as much as the number of unique `locale` entries in the first table ) :

```
SELECT t2.`group`
     , t2.`item`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(t1.locale = 'en', t2.`text`, NULL)) AS en
     ...
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(t1.locale = 'fr', t2.`text`, NULL)) AS fr
FROM `language_entries` t2 
LEFT JOIN `languages` t1 ON t1.`id` = t2.`language_id`
GROUP BY t2.`group`,
         t2.`item`
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5568/1)

Comment: Rename table `table2` to `language_entries` then `table` to `languages` and it indeed works. I will credit you the 150 rep if no one else submits a better alternative in 23 hours. Thank You!